# Getting actual file type using Struts2 s:file control

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, file-io, struts2

I am using Struts2 File control s:file.

JSP code

```
<s:file name="user.batchFile" />
```

Action class code

```
new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(getUser().getBatchFile());
```

It returns application/octet-stream.

I am uploading CSV file. Is their any way I can get text/csv. I want to validate the file, that user should only upload the actual file. Not some other system file. Or not by changing it's ext to csv too.

How can I get the actual file type?

Comment: If you need to identify the mimetype without relying on filename extensions, there are a [variety of libraries](http://www.aeonscope.net/2007/12/18/java-mime-libraries/) that can help determine mimetype once you have the file, but you are at the mercy of the client and configuration regarding what's recorded in the action.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to define following mutator methods

```
 private File file;
 private String contentType;
 private String filename;

 public void setUpload(File file) {
         this.file = file;
      }

      public void setUploadContentType(String contentType) {
         this.contentType = contentType;
      }

      public void setUploadFileName(String filename) {
         this.filename = filename;
      }
```

Where

`setX(File file) :   The file that contains the content of the uploaded file`
`setXContentType(String contentType) : The mime type of the uploaded file`
`setXFileName(String fileName) :Actual file name`

Please read the official documentation for details

[file-upload](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/file-upload.html)

[how-do-we-upload-files](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/how-do-we-upload-files.html)

Additionally if you want to restrict the upload file type you can even do using declarative as

```
<action name="doUpload" class="com.example.UploadAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="allowedTypes">image/jpeg,image/gif</param>
    </interceptor-ref> 
    <result name="success">good_result.jsp</result>
</action>
```

But Programmatically limiting the file type using the information passed in to your Action class via the `setXContentType(String contentType)` method is much flexible that this

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap` mime mapping. You should instead get the mime type by [`ServletContext#getMimeType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getMimeType%28java.lang.String%29). It uses `<mime-mapping>` entries of the `web.xml` which you can customize/override. In for example Tomcat, a default list is definied in `/conf/web.xml`. You can add it there or in webapp's own `web.xml` as follows:

```xml
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>csv</extension>
    <mime-type>text/csv</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Then you can get it as follows:

```
String contentType = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getMimeType(fileName);
// ...
```

Be aware that this relies on a proper file extension. If the file has a different extension then you need to throw a validation error on that. If you'd like to validate the actual file content, just pass it through a decent CSV parser. If it chokes, then throw a validation error on that as well.